# Is there a way to print long int and int with the same format flag?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I have a code which defines an index type so that if a user knows that their index space remains in the realm of a normal integer they can use `int` instead of `long int`.

```
    #ifdef LONG_IDX
    typedef long int idx_type
    #else
    typedef int idx_type
    #endif
```

I have some `printf` statements in my code to print out this index data and I don't want to wrap them in `#ifdef` statements all over the place.  Is there a format flag to specify that the argument may be a `long int` or an `int`?  If not, is there a way to define a custom format flag that I could simply add to my index type definition?

Comment: I'd guess the C++ answer to this would be to stop using `printf` and instead using cout style output.

Comment: If you need format strings, use boost format and positional format specifiers

Comment: Your text says `long int`, but your code says `long long int`.

Comment: I believe in @Damien_The_Unbeliever. :)

Comment: The answer depends on whether this is C or C++ code. It's tagged both. Do you need a C answer?

Comment: I need the `printf` (C).  Some people still use `printf` in C++ so I tagged it there as well.  Personally I think `printf` can be less cumbersome (in most cases, but not this one haha) for complex formatting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can conditionally define a formatter for your index type:

```
#ifdef LONG_IDX
typedef long long int idx_type
#define IDX_FORMAT "lld"
#else
typedef int idx_type
#define IDX_FORMAT "d"
#endif
```

Then you of course need to use this in the formatting calls, which can become a bit cumbersome and (as always!) requires you to be vigilant and remember to do it right when you want to print an index:

```
idx_type my_index = 47;

print("my_index = %" IDX_FORMAT, my_index);
```

Note how the above uses C's automatic concatenation of adjacent string literals to "build" the proper formatting string at compile-time. This is a typical usage of that awesome feature of C's syntax.

Also, if your compiler is nice enough to do formatting string validation (GCC does), you will very likely get helpful warnings if you do mess up and forget to use the `defined` string somewhere.

Comment: This is how I'd do it. And the question is marked with both C and C++, and this will work in both. So +1. However, I do like the simplicity and elegance of Richard's answer as well.

Comment: What's wrong with `"%j"` and casting to `intmax_t`?  That's what they were designed for.

Comment: @James I'm not seeing any real documentation on the `%j` flag at my usual resources ([c++.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/))  Could you point me to a good source for this?

Comment: @Mosby I usually use the Single UNIX Specification: you'll have to register at http://www.unix.org/online.html.  The specification includes the extensions required by Posix and the Open Group, but they're all clearly identified.  (The Linux man pages are also very good, but they don't distinguish what is Unix extension and what isn't.)  If nothing else, Wikipedia also describes `"%j"`.  But there's not much to it: it's just a width modifier for the following format specifiers, e.g. `"%jd"` is just like `"%d"`, except that it takes an `intmax_t`.  (Note that it is C99, not C90.)

Answer (score 9):

I would use `%lli` (long long integer), and do a cast when you print it:

```
idx_type idx;

printf("%lli", (long long int) idx);
```

I think that gives you the most reliability on what will be printed.

Comment: In this case.  The general solution would be to use `"%j"` and cast to `intmax_t`.  (But of course, this is a problem that C++ programmers don't have.)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to always cast "up".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c = 1;
    int i = 12;
    long int l = 123;
    long long int ll = 1234;

    printf("c=%lld i=%lld l=%lld ll=%lld\n", 
            (long long int) c, 
            (long long int) i, 
            (long long int) l, 
            (long long int) ll
          );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Richard: You assume that your formatting style is superior? I prefer kommaas at the beginning of lines, because they stand out better that way.

Comment: It wasn't about the commas, but more about the line-indentation. change it back if you'd like, just make sure your indentation makes it easy to read.

Comment: You may indent whatever you want, but don't touch my commaas. BTW, even though I did not indent at the first brace (I never do), the code was readable. BTW2: Why didn't you cleanup the sloppy whitespace near the initialisers?

Answer (score -3):

Either use `%d` for decimal in printf or `std::cout` printing.

Comment: `%d` is the same as `%i`, meaning exactly `int`.

Comment: Oh damn. My C has indeed become a little rusty.